# CORS запрос к PERL серверу и JSON ответ

Tags: javascript, perl, cors

Добрый день

Новичок. Начинаю пытаться осваивать PERL и JS. Стоит задача делать кроссдоменные запросы. Пробую тестировать на простом примере для дальнейшей усложненной реализации. Составленный пример, разумеется нерабочий. Пока пытаюсь просто получить true от запроса (пока false). Пожалуйста, помогите cделать true и, если возможно, обработчик JSON ответа. В сети не нашел нормальных примеров по CORS и настройки ответов сервера, особенно на PERL. Пожалуйста, пните лузера в нужную сторону, желательно, исправив мой пример, не используя модули. Что бы не позориться, прикрепляю ссылки:
Код JS: [http://a.ru/ctest.html](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kVjehA3sNCasDTuGJKig-Spj7OcxJHRpSrn-GmbBXeg/edit?usp=sharing)
Код PERL: [http://b.ru/cgi-bin/ctest.cgi](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ANrgMtLzixmM05DBXLAJ4BXrZWDctL-vQ58qlE8USB0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А у вас за пунктик на счёт модулей?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - не занимайтесь изобретением велосипедов а-ля ручное формирование JSON. Для этого есть модуль [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) (и его XS-версия [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS)). Ваш пример мог бы выглядеть так:

```
use JSON qw/to_json/;
my %data = ( 'a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B' );
# ...
print to_json( \%data );
```

Дальше, по мелочам:

1. Не используйте переменные с именами `$a` и `$b`. Конечно, в данном контексте это не приведёт ни к чему страшному, но хорошие привычки лучше вырабатывать сразу.
2. Любой перловый исходник должен начинаться со строк:

`use strict; use warnings;`

или

```
use Modern::Perl;
```

В любом случае вам нужно сначала разобраться с основами.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. use strict; use warnings; знаю, но пока почти однострочники, не пользуюсь. Написал небольшое приложение с обработкой форм, там использую. По поводу CORS запроса не подскажите? Как его правильно отправить и что бы PERL правильно ответил. В сети практически нет примеров по серверной реализации,даже на php. Будь очень полезный пример для всех.

Comment: @Android88, совет тот же: не изобретить велосипедов. [Раз](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::CORS), [два](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::CORS). Если не используете сами фреймворки (в смысле Dancer или Mojo), то смотрите как там всё устроено.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня задача с сайта a.ru (html с JS) отправлять CORS правильный запрос на сайт b.ru (PERL сервер), a.ru получать ответ от b.ru и обрабатывать его JS. Как мне кажется, это возможно реализовать,  переделав/дополнив мой краткий пример. Ввиду дефицита информации в интернете и книгах решил обратиться сюда, так как уже потратил немало времени на поиск и попытку реализации.

Comment: Страница cgi сейчас возвращает json. При обращение по ссылке. Как добиться того, что бы он возвращал его по CORS запросу из и в a.ru и обрабатывался. Т.е. вероятно проблема уже в JS в a.ru

Comment: А чем, по-вашему, CORS-запрос отличается от "обычного" CGI? С точки зрения принимающего его - ничем. Ну разве что анализ `Origin`  нужен и заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` в ответе. В общем, в спецификации `CORS` всё расписано подробно, пока не очень понятно в чём заключаются ваши сложности.

Comment: Тем, что функция callOtherDomain() возвращает 'false' и почти нет опыта, что бы понять, что делаю не так) я добавил в .htaccess "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"" и убрал его из cgi, так как он вероятно неправильно прописывался. Но все пока четно.

Comment: А вы вообще понимаете суть `CORS`? Что откуда должно уходить, как на что реагировать и т.д.  Такое ощущение, что вы просто либо не до конца разобрались в самой технологии, либо не знаете толком языков, на которых пытаетесь писать. Я не знаю чем тут помочь, так как не понимаю сути затруднений.

Comment: Надеюсь, что да)... Мне необходимо, что бы JS с одного сайта (a.ru) получал данные с PERL сервера (другого сайта b.ru) и обрабатывал их... Вот и вся задача. Сейчас данный запрос не проходит. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: что бы делать правильный CORS запрос , получать правильный ответ, и если возможно обрабатывать его. Если возможно на простом рабочем примере, который можно загрузить на perl сервер и проверить. Повторюсь, что почему то в сети не нашел нормальных примеров обоюдной реализации: JS код и код сервера. Поэтому пришел сюда к гуру. Возможно я что то не так фундаментально понимаю)

Comment: Сейчас переделал http://a.ru https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kVjehA3sNCasDTuGJKig-Spj7OcxJHRpSrn-GmbBXeg/edit получаю ответ "undefined" а хотелось увидеть данные JSON. (( В общем сами знаете: первые шаги даются сложно...)

Comment: Поменял otvet на имя пременной JSON с b.ru и получил ее значение на a.ru.  Надеюсь я получил кроссдоменный запрос))). Спасибо за участие))

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть модуль [Mojolicious::Plugin::CORS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious-Plugin-CORS-0.01/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/CORS.pm). Просто подключаете и ваше приложение будет автоматически устанавливать заголовки `CORS`. Подключать так:

```
package App;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->plugin( 'Mojolicious::Plugin::CORS' );
}
```

Это в случае, если у вас на бэке `Mojo`

А вообще, Если заглянуть в [исходник модуля](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/AMIRITE/Mojolicious-Plugin-CORS-0.01/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/CORS.pm), то там можно увидеть, что устанавливается 4 заголовка:

```
$c->res->headers->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*' );
$c->res->headers->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' );
$c->res->headers->header( 'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600 );
$c->res->headers->header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With' );
```